# tableView editing mode -iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to remove the minus sign when in editing mode and displaying only the reorder icon?

Trying since long time. Somehow succeeded in removing the indentation of table but still failed to remove the minus sign.

Also i want the reorder icon appear permanently on screen so the table view will always be in editing mode

Is there any option to do this???Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this (I don't think I have ever seen it implemented) but if it were to work I think you do this by returning `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` as the cell's editing style in

`- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

As long as you have

```
- (void)tableView:(UTableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toindexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
```

and

```
-(BOOL)tableview:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

defined in the UITableViewDelegate the reordering controls should display when you enter edit mode.

To start in editing style call

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

after your view gets loaded

Comment: i got the answer last day

      - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    return YES;
}



This is all i need to implement... anywways thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked...

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable. 
 UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
 return YES;
}
```

hAPPY iCODING...