# UITableView with draggable rows with value pickers

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to display 3 rows from which a user can pick values by selecting any row: http://cl.ly/9SFy

For example, when I pick the first row, a list of values appear (kinda a picker view).

Also, it should be possible to drag and reorder the rows.

How do you suggest to implement this on iPhone ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a UITableView that displays all of the rows.

You can manage reordering of the cells easily (see the [Managing the Reordering of Rows section of the Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html)
).

Apple supplies a UIPickerView already; all you have to do is present a modal view containing the picker view whenever the user taps on a cell (using `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`).

Comment: thanks. Can I fix the number of rows to 3 (no possible add or delete them - you don't see anymore the respective icons) ?

Comment: Also, can I enable the dragging feature without having to select edit ? I want my table rows being draggable, but also selectable (to open the modalView)

Comment: To answer the first question, you can set `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to return 3 each time.
See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511758/tableview-editing-mode-iphone) for how to enter edit mode without pressing a button.